# android gps source code modification and recompile

Tags: android, gps

I'm working on a android project, and I have to modify some gps code. I follow some instruction on Internet, find the .c file. Now, if I want to do some change on this file, then recompile it and put it into a handset, how to do that?
thanks a lot!

Comment: that won't work. android uses java code, not c - you would need to port it

Comment: I may be wrong here, but Android is native c. "Android consists of a kernel based on the Linux kernel, with middleware, libraries and APIs written in C and application software running on an application framework which includes Java-compatible libraries based on Apache Harmony"

Comment: jack, could you tell me how to compile the modified android kernel code?

Comment: Did you had any progress with this?